# Klein PHP route not working

Tags: php

I have the beginnings of an application that i've picked up from another developer who's chosen Klein as the routing framework. I more familiar with Slim but still for the life of me can't figure out why the following doesn't work:

```
$klein->respond('GET', '/?', function($request, $response) {
    echo 'this works!'
});
$klein->respond('GET', '/[i:id]', function($request, $response) {
   echo 'This returns 404 not found';
});
$klein->dispatch();
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

In my httpd.conf I have "AllowOverride All"

I'm sure this is pretty straight forward but for the life of me I can't figure out why the second route doesn't work.

Comment: Lol I dunno why I put echo in the 404 one, but hey you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider both route patterns.

`'/?'` route pattern matches `scheme:host` and `schema:hostname/`. `/` is optional.

`/[i:id]` route pattern matches `scheme:host/id` where id is an integer.

Terminating the request uri with a `/` (for example `scheme:host/2/`) for the later route pattern will not match unless the route pattern is updated to match this case.

In order to match this case, use `/[i:id]/?` for the route pattern.